# JQuery not able to parse JSP EL

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, el

My JQuery `process.js` file is not able to parse JSP EL expression. I am just tyring to display a List object in my JSP. If I just use the `${students}` object it works correctly and displays all the students but if I try to display it using JQuery it just displays the `${students}` string as it is in the browser. I have disabled scripting in my `web.xml` and using EL for displaying data.

Is there any other way to handle this?

**Browser Output:**

```
Hello World from JQuery!

From JSP:  
[Student{id=1, name=Jack}, Student{id=2, name=Jill}]

From JQuery:
${students}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/process.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv"></div>
        <h2>From JSP: <p/> ${students}</h2>
        <h3>From JQuery: <div id="studentDiv"></div></h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

**process.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //static message
    var msg = "Hello World from JQuery!";
    $("#mydiv").text(msg);

    //dynamic message
    var students = '${students}';
    $("#studentDiv").text(students);
});
```

**HomePageController.java**

```
@WebServlet(name = "HomePageController", urlPatterns = {"/homePageController.do"})
public class HomePageController extends BaseController {

    private static final String VIEW_NAME = "/jsp/home.jsp";

    @Override
    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Student> students = getAllStudents();
        request.setAttribute("students", students);
        request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VIEW_NAME).forward(request, response);
    }

    private List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        Student student1 = new Student(1, "Jack");
        Student student2 = new Student(2, "Jill");
        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);
        System.out.println("students = " + students);
        return students;
    }
}
```

**BaseController.java**

```
public abstract class BaseController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    public abstract void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException;

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <!-- Disable scripting -->
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: .js files are not executed by server-side processes, therefore any server side variables will be rendered simply as plain text. If you need this behaviour you need to place the `${students}` output where it will be rendered correctly, such as in a `data` attribute in your HTML, and then read it via the DOM through JS.

Comment: I think you've missed a core concept. JSP EL is executed serverside and produces html / javascript which is sent to the browser. jQuery runs on the client browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL expressions are evaluated by `JspServlet` (`*.jsp`) and `FacesServlet` (`*.xhtml`) only. However, `.js` files are by default not processed by those servlets, but by container's builtin default servlet. This is not jQuery's fault. This is just your fault.

A quick trick is to add `*.js` URL pattern to the `JspServlet` mapping. After figuring out the name of the container's builtin `JspServlet`, which is in Tomcat and clones `jsp`, add the below entry to your webapp's `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Alternatives are:

1. Refactor it to webservice call and use `$.getJSON()`.
2. Print it as HTML5 `data` attribute and use `$.data()`.
3. Print it as an inline script variable in JSP before desired script is included.

Comment: Thanks!  Got it working by using the 2nd alternative you suggested above, which is using HTML5 `data` attribute and use of `$.data()` jquery method