# EL return by ResponseBody doesnt work on jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, jsp, el

my  page do paging script on $(document).ready() function
    and it call controller using ajax
    success function of ajax like this

```
function(data){
    $("#target").html(data);
}
```

and my controller does return String like 
    ..... ${list[i(index of loop)].member}(!this is my question) ...

so my page work on div,,classes,,but only ${} doesn't work and it
    print on browser this it's own form(${list[i].member})

i use annotation on my mapped method

i use spring 4 eclipse, chrome browser, tomcat 8.5, oracle 10 database

````
```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/news_list.do")
    public String newslist(@RequestParam("page") String page) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String res = "";
        int cnt = Integer.parseInt(page);
        String f1 = "${newslist[";
        String f2 = "].";
        String f3 = "}";
        for(int i =cnt ;i<cnt+10 ;i++ ) {
            System.out.println("asdasd"+i);
            res +="<div class='row mb-2'>"
                    + "<div class='col-md-12'>"
                    + "<div class='card bg-warning'>"
                    + "<div class='card-body'>"
                    + "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-4'>"
                    + "<img src='http://www.3forty.media/cannix/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/clem-onojeghuo-127166-unsplash-1-500x333.jpg'>"
                    + "</div><div class='col-md-8'>"
                    + "<div class='news_title'>"
                    + "<h5><a href='' onclick='newsnumfind();' value="
                    + f1 + i + f2 + "news_number" + f3
                    + "> "
                    + "${newslist["+i+"].title}"
                    + " </a></h5></div>"
                    + "<div class='news-cats'><ul class='list-unstyled list-inline mb-1'>"
                    + "<li class='list-inline-item'><iclass='fa fa-folder-o text-danger'></i>"
                    + "<a href='news_body.do'><small> "
                    + f1 + i + f2 + "category" + f3
                    + " </small></a></li>"
                    + "<li class='list-inline-item'><i class='fa fa-folder-o text-danger'></i>"
                    + "<a href='news_body.do'><small>"
                    + f1 + i + f2 + "author" + f3
                    + "</small></a></li>"
                    + "<li class='list-inline-item'><iclass='fa fa-folder-o text-danger'></i>"
                    + "<a href='news_body.do'><small>"
                    + f1 + i + f2 + "postTime" + f3
                    + "</small></a></li></ul></div>"
                    + "<div class='news-content'><p>"
                    + f1 + i + f2 + "contents" + f3
                    + "</p></div>"
                    + "<div class='news-buttons'><a href=''>"
                    + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm' value="
                    + f1 + i + f2 + "news_number" + f3
                    + " onclick = 'newsnumfind();'>본문 보기</button>"
                    + "</a></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>";
        }


        return res;
    }
```

i expect list by html tags and E'L value
but only html does work and E'L print it's own literals
````

Comment: my ajax are like this$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "news_list.do?page=" + cnt,
   dataType : "text",
   success : function(data){
    $("#news1").html(data);
   },
   errer : function(){
    alert("asas");
   }
  });

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151409/jquery-not-able-to-parse-jsp-el) out .